# SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server

I have heard the SQL Server 2005 supports C# in the creation of stored procedures. Is this true? If so, does SQL Server support all CLI compliant languages? For instance, could I use RPG from this list: http://www.dotnetpowered.com/languages.aspx

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its true. You can create stored procedures in any [CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131094.aspx) [language](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131045.aspx)